# How can I resolve this problem? I can't find a woking state for this error

Tags: solidity, remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

contract TicTacToe
{
    //Verifica daca mesajul are valoare sau nu
    modifier has_value {
      if(msg.value > 0)
        _;
    }

    // Structura principala+informatiile jocului
    struct Game
    {
        uint balance;
        uint turn;
        address opposition;
        uint time_limit;
        mapping(uint => mapping(uint => uint)) board;
        bool isSet;
    }

    //Tine minte jocurile curente
    mapping (address => Game) games;

    //Functia actionata de host pentru a incepe jocul
    function start() public has_value payable
    {
        // adauga o structura a jocului
        Game storage g = games[msg.sender];
        // verifica daca pe acceasi adresa s-a initializat alt joc
        if(g.balance == 0)
        {
            g.isSet = true;
            restart(msg.sender);
            g.balance += msg.value;
        }
    }
```

error :
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> tic_tac_toe.sol:49:28:
|
49 | if(g.opposition == addres(0) && msg.sender != host)
| ^^^^^^

How can I get this working properly?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error it seems like you missed an `s` in `address(0)`.

```
if(g.opposition == address(0) && msg.sender != host)
```

But you didn't even paste the line which gives the error.
Next time try to paste only the lines that generates the error